# change system time on iPhone using an app?

Tags: iphone, time

Is it possible to change the device system time in an app, if so, how? I realize there are many reasons not to do this, but I assure you I have good reason!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the device system time from an app (at least if you try to do this on a non-jailbroken device).